# react-router-bootstrap - Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-router-dom` and `react-router-bootstrap` to handle routing in my react-typescript-react-bootstrap web app and I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
Routes@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60069:7
Router@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60006:7
```

The project isn't throwing any errors but the routing is not responding. Here's the index and components:

index.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <SiteNav />
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/home" element={Home} />
              <Route path="/about" element={About} />
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

SiteNav.tsx

```
class SiteNav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Nav">
                <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                    <Container>
                        <LinkContainer to="/home">
                            <Navbar.Brand>The Pirate Hostel</Navbar.Brand>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="me-auto">
                                <LinkContainer to="/home">
                                    <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
                                </LinkContainer>
                                <LinkContainer to="/about">
                                    <Nav.Link>About</Nav.Link>
                                </LinkContainer>
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Container>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SiteNav;
```

home.tsx

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home">
                <body>home</body>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

about.tsx

```
class About extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="About">
                <body>About</body>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default About;
```

What am I missing?

edit---- updated with the following but still getting the same error

```
const About = () =>  {
    <div className="About">
        <body>About</body>
    </div>
}

export default About

const Home = () =>  {
            <div className="Home">
                <body>home</body>
            </div>
}


export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component's API changed a bit. The `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`, i.e. JSX, not a reference to the component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```